# Web API C# how to allow post for an object model if its an optional field

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, .net-6.0

I am new to Web API. I am trying to see if we can submit a POST request without optional fields.

My object model

```
public class MyAddress
    {
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty( NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore )]
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Controller

```
[Route( "api/[controller]" )]
[ApiController]
public class AddressController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType( typeof( MyAddressDto ), 200 )]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync( MyAddress address )
    {
        return Created( string.Empty, "Call received" );
    }
}
```

Is there a way POST request can default to Null if the State and City fields are not supplied in FormBody?

Example POST request:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:7088/api/Address' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "address1": "address line 1",
  "address2": "address line 2",
  "city": "city"
}'
```

This is the error message I receive for the above POST

```
{
  "errors": {
    "State": [
      "The State field is required."
    ]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-cd38c09edb586fcfcf155732f3af8f14-421285519485f996-00"
}
```

At present I am unable to make a successful POST call without passing the field State and City.

I am using NewtonsoftJson 6.0.20

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fields are optional mark them as ones via [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) (i.e. `string` -> `string?`) :

```
public class MyAddress
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string? State { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty( NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore )]
    public string? City { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Guru Stron, 
But considering the case of Address its more of a common object model. In some cases I require State and City which I handle in UI. 
Is there a way to make the model bind if passed and ignore if not?

Comment: @user1417294 just create a DTO then. It will make your life that much easier.